# "Next Comments" button

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

So I want to make a simple shoutbox using MySQL and PHP and I know enough of both languages to produce it rather easily. Also I know how to limit it to only show the last 5-10 or whatever comments at a time. However, what would be the process of making it so the shoutbox only shows the last 5 comments and then there is a button that says "Older Comments" and it shows the next 5 and so on and then another button that says "Newer Comments" and it goes back a page. I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing that without writing tons and tons of code.

Here is the code I have for my shoutbox:

**addmessage.php**

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if ($_POST['shoutname'] and $_POST['shout'] !== " ") {
    if (isset($_POST['shoutname'])) {
        $shoutname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shoutname']);
        $shout = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shout']);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO shoutbox (name, shout) VALUES ('$shoutname','$shout')");
        mysql_close($bd);
    }
}

header("Location: shoutbox.php");
?>
```

(config.php contains my mysql connection information)

**shoutbox.php**

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo $info['name']. "<br>";
        echo $info['shout']. "<br>";
    }
?>
<form method="post" action="addmessage.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="shoutname" /><br />
Message: <input type="text" name="shout" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I'm just not sure how to make a button that shows the *next* five comments ordered by id and so on.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the message next to the first 5 messages by inserting an offset into your mysql query. It will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT [OFFSET],[LIMIT]
```

You could post the offset as a request parameter that has been automatically generated in your shoutbox.php file.

See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

**shoutbox.php**

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1);
$start = ($page * 5) - 5;
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.",5");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo $info['name']. "<br>";
        echo $info['shout']. "<br>";
    }
?>
<a href="shoutbox.php?page=<?php echo $page+1;?>">Next 5 messages</a>
<form method="post" action="addmessage.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="shoutname" /><br />
Message: <input type="text" name="shout" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**conditional Next & Previous:**

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1);
$start = ($page * 5) - 5;
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.",5");
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo $info['name']. "<br>";
        echo $info['shout']. "<br>";
    }
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) AS count FROM shoutbox");
    $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    $count = $count['count'];
    if($start + 5 < $count)
        echo '<a href="shoutbox.php?page='. ($page+1) .'">Next 5 messages</a>';
    if($count > 0 && $start>0)
        echo '<a href="shoutbox.php?page='. ($page-1) .'">Previous 5 messages</a>';
?>
<form method="post" action="addmessage.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="shoutname" /><br />
Message: <input type="text" name="shout" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: That gave me a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /shoutbox.php on line 12 error and line 12 is $page = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1));

Comment: can you try now please

Comment: okay that worked, and from that code I was able to make a previous 5 comments button, but is there a way to make it so that each button only shows up when there are actual comments? I.E. When the page loads there is no "Previous comments" button and on the last page of comments there is no "Next comments" button?

Comment: check it now with conditional previous and next buttons

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line     if($start+5 < $count)

Comment: ok i just forgot `;` for `$count = mysql_fetch_array($q)`
try it now

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'in line         echo '<a href="shoutbox.php?page='.$page+1.'">Next 5 messages</a>';

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT OFFSET,LIMIT

in your case FOR older comments first time your OFFSET would be 0 and LIMIT 5
THEN 
OFFSET 5 and LIMIT 5
THEN 
OFFSET 10 and LIMIT 5
SO ON....

for newer comments run it in reverse order